# Why does a part of the background turn white when the image disappears? Photo attached

Tags: java, slick

I have an image of a fish that I've drawn to the screen, which has a transparent background:

[image: Fish image]

When the ninja touches the fish, I want the fish only to disappear, without affecting the background. Instead, the fish disappears when the ninja touches it but the surrounding part of the background also disappears with it:

[image: background disappears with image when ninja touches image]

I have no idea why this is happening and I'd love some help as I am truly stuck! I have a feeling it may have something to do with the **destroy() method** I am using...

Here is the relevant Java code:

```
 if((characterY >= RandomY) && (characterX >= RandomX)){
     enemy.destroy();
 }

/* enemy is the fish image object, RandomX and RandomY are the fish's co-ordinates 
on the screen (randomly positioned each time), and characterX and characterY 
are the ninja's co-ordinates on the map. */

//Render method:

public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
        background.draw();
        enemy.draw(RandomX, RandomY);
        ninja.draw(characterX, characterY);
    }
```

I am using Slick2D + LWJGL if that helps.

Comment: How the game handles drawing?

Comment: @trollingchar I've updated the code with my render method

Comment: what does enemy.draw() do after an enemy has been destroy()ed?

Comment: You probably should check if the enemy is destroyed before drawing it.